# Serialize and Deserialize an RSA public key

Tags: java

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(1024);
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
Key privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
```

I want to create just the public key from a `byte[]`.

I have tried this as an experiment:

```
publicKey = new SecretKeySpec(publicKey.getEncoded(), publicKey.getAlgorithm());
```

But decryption using that key then fails.

I have also tried serializing the key with `ObjectOutputStream`, but serialization fails.

> java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLKey

I read [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/522854/java-io/java/serialize-java-security-key) that I can't use `SecretKeySpec` with RSA.

> so as long as you are talking of a SecretKey and not an RSA or DSA key then you don't have to go through any contortions involving KeyGenerator or the like.

Anyone know how to perform these contortions or a way of doing this.

Comment: For RSA there is [RSAPrivateKeySpec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/RSAPrivateKeySpec.html)

Comment: @tuxayo Yeah, that's in an answer below already.

Comment: Where? I only see mentions of PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.

Anyway I couldn't make RSAPrivateKeySpec work and ended up using PKCS8EncodedKeySpec. Should I delete my first comment which can be misleading?

Comment: @tuxayo Sorry, I got mixed up with `RSAPublicKeySpec`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Asymmetric keys like those from RSA are usually stored in X509 format. Therefor you can use `X509EncodedKeySpec`instead.

A simple example is already in the Java 7 JavaDoc (just replace DSA with RSA):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html

```
X509EncodedKeySpec bobPubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bobEncodedPubKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey bobPubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(bobPubKeySpec);
```

If you need to deserialize the private from `byte[]`, I've found that you must use `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`.

Answer (score 7):

Depends on what do you want to do with the serialized representation. If the consumer is no one but your own program, feel free to roll your own implementation. A public RSA key consists of two integers - exponent and modulus. Modulus is large - around 1024 bits, exponent is typically on the order of 17 bits. Both are available as `BigInteger` objects if you cast your public key object to `RSAPublicKey`.

So, to recap:

```
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey)kp.getPublic();
return publicKey.getModulus().toString() + "|" +
    publicKey.getPublicExponent().toString();
```

That's sufficient to restore the key. To deserialize:

```
String []Parts = MyKeyString.split("\\|");
RSAPublicKeySpec Spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(
        new BigInteger(Parts[0]),
        new BigInteger(Parts[1]));
return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(Spec);
```

If the key needs to be passed to third party software, you better serialize to a standard format - PEM or DER.

Comment: Nice option, helps understand what's going on, but `getEncoded()` and the `X509EncodedKeySpec` for deserialization are enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to convert a `PubliKey` to PEM Base64 format

```
String publicKeyString = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(publicKey.getEncoded());
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: How can you restore from the byte array the original key?