# Java Kryonet RSAPublicKeyImpl not registered

Tags: java, kryo, kryonet

I'm trying to send a PublicKey (java.security.PublicKey) from a Kryonet server to a client by using `connection.sendTCP(key);` I get this exception when doing so:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.class);
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getRegistration(Kryo.java:443)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.writeClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:73)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClass(Kryo.java:475)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:568)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoSerialization.write(KryoSerialization.java:50)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.TcpConnection.send(TcpConnection.java:192)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection.sendTCP(Connection.java:59)
at darpix.accountManager.AccountManager$1.received(AccountManager.java:93)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener$QueuedListener$3.run(Listener.java:102)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have registered these five classes:

```
k.register(AccountRequest.class);
k.register(AccountResponse.class);
k.register(KeyResponse.class);
k.register(PublicKey.class);
k.register(byte[].class);
```

I haven't used RSAPublicKeyImpl anywhere in my code and I can't seem to find it anywhere in the libraries I'm using.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606428/serialize-and-deserialize-an-rsa-public-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not a full answer but too much for comments.

Java crypto (JCA/JCE) publishes (documents) a series of generic 'facade' classes like `Signature Cipher Key` etc. but the actual implementation classes for a large variety of algorithms and variants are provided by a variable set of cryptoproviders, may vary across cryptoproviders or versions, and are not published or stable -- except for the conformance to their parent classes and interfaces that is required by OO rules. Many though by no means all of these implementation classes are under `sun.*` or `com.sun.*` .

Usual Java serialization and deserialization is not defined to work on crypto objects. **A correct way to transmit or store a key is not to use the key object but instead an *encoding* of the key,** which is a standardized byte sequence defined to be stable across implementations and versions.

In the sender you can call `Key.getEncoded()` which is inherited by `PublicKey` and `PrivateKey` among others, although the encodings they use are different (X.509 and PKCS#8 respectively) and send the resulting bytes. In the receiver use `KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm[,provider])` to obtain a key factory for the correct algorithm, then call `.generatePublic` or `.generatePrivate` with respectively an `X509EncodedKeySpec` or `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` containing the X.509 or PKCS#8 encoding. Note the receiver needs to know the algorithm, which may need to be sent in addition; this is technically redundant because an algorithm identifier is included in the (standard) PKCS#8 and X.509 encodings but not trivial to extract.

I don't know how (or if) to integrate this with kryo.

Note that externalizing a private key unencrypted is supported, but often insecure. It is usually preferable to transmit or store keypairs containing a private key in a `KeyStore`, which is serialized to or deserialized from a stream (often a file) in encrypted form using `.store` and `.load`. Although public keys do not need to be encrypted, it is often insecure to transmit or store them without *authentication* which is usually done by putting them in a certificate, usually an X.509v3 certificate, which similarly is encoded as a byte sequence (that is actually pretty widely implemented).

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!